Why does variance decomposition not exist in logistic regression?
I'm quite confused when reading some materials, it says the reason we use pseudo R-square in logistic regression is that the variance decomposition cannot hold.
I get the idea that the variance of $y$ is $p(1-p)$, which directly follows the mean $p$, so adding another parameter, "variance",  into the model would be unnecessary. But why exactly cannot we do variance decomposition? It seems to me the calculation does not require any specifications of the population distribution, and the middle term still vanishes.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar{y})^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{y_i}+\hat{y_i}-\bar{y})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2 +\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y_i}-\bar{y})^2$$
Thank you in advance!

Variances--and your calculation--have nothing at all to do with logistic regression.  There is no such thing as "the mean $p$" because $p$ depends on the explanatory variables.  What are you trying to ask, then?

@whuber Yes, I know the variance has nothing to do with logistic regression. Maybe I'm a bit unclear - the problem I'm asking is why we cannot do variance decomposition in logistic regression and then use the pseudo R-square to measure the goodness-of-fit of this model. (the mean $p$ I said is because I saw some explanations on this question which state that the "variance" of this binary $y$ should follow the "mean". But I'm quite confused about this statement :(

I guess you could use such a metric to assess goodness of fit.  But even $R^2$ itself, in ordinary least squares regression, is at best a comparative measure and what makes it effective is that its distribution under useful null hypotheses can be computed.  Since neither of those is the case for logistic regression, you might find it more fruitful to study the methods people have already come up with for assessing goodness of fit.  Most are conceptually related to $R^2$ but based on deviances rather than squared residuals.

@Emma_Zieger Splitting up the total sum of squares does not work in logistic regression. You can verify that for your own data. In general, for non-linear models (like a logistic) it will not work. You may find this link useful:  https://www.statforbiology.com/2022/stat_general_r2/.

The middle term does NOT vanish.

Splitting up the total sum of squares $\sum{(y-\bar{y})^2}$ into two parts is based on the following.
$\sum{(y-\bar{y})^2}= 
\sum{[(y-\hat{y})+(\hat{y}-\bar{y})]}^2 = 
\sum{(y-\hat{y})^2 + \sum{(\hat{y}-\bar{y})}^2} + 2\sum{(y-\hat{y})(\hat{y}-\bar{y})}$
The final term $2\sum{(y-\hat{y})(\hat{y}-\bar{y})}$ can be written as:
$2\sum{\hat{y}(y-\hat{y})} - 2\bar{y}\sum{(y-\hat{y})} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(1)$
For logistic regression it holds that $\sum{(y-\hat{y}})=0$. This follows from the normal equations for logistic regression. These are, in case of an intercept $b_0$ and a single predictor $x$ with regression effect $b_1$:
$\sum{(y-\hat{y})}=0$ and $\sum{(y-\hat{y})}x=0$
The first term in expression (1) above however is not equal to zero! In linear regression it is, but not in logistic. That is because for logistic, $\hat{y}$ is not a linear transformation of $x$.
Conclusion: unlike linear regression, in logistic regression the total sum squares of $y$ cannot be split into the two sums of squares SSresidual and SSregression. And hence, other measures than R-square are used to express goodness of fit, like those based on the deviance of a model, as @whuber already pointed out.
Here is an R script which I hope is self explaining with the added comments.
X <- 1:20
Ybin <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1)

model <- glm(Ybin ~ X, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(model)
yhat <- predict(model, type="response")

ggplot()+geom_point(aes(X,yhat))

SSreg <- sum((yhat - mean(Ybin))^2)
SStot <- sum((Ybin - mean(Ybin))^2)
SSres <- sum((Ybin - yhat)^2)

# Two times the sum of the products of the "error" and 
# the "distance to the mean explained by regression" must be added as well
# to the two sums of squares to obtain the total sum of squares. 
Scross <- 2*sum((Ybin - yhat)*(yhat - mean(Ybin)))
# Or instead:
Scross <- 2*sum((Ybin - yhat)*yhat )


# Below the total sum of squares appears not to be equal to the sum of
# the residuals sum of squares and the regression sum of squares, as is
# the case in linear regression.!
# Instead, the sum of products of errors and regression-distance-to-mean
# has to be added as wel.
SStot
SSreg + SSres
SSreg + SSres + Scross


# The two normal equations for logistic regression imply that both expressions should be zero:
sum(Ybin-yhat)
sum((Ybin-yhat)*X)

# For linear regression the following term is zero, but not for logistic regression:
2*sum((Ybin - yhat)*yhat)

#- - - - - - Important conclusion - - - - -

# This final expression not being zero leads to the impossibility to split up
# the total sum of squares in the usual way. 

